# How to customize Wordpress dashboard for different users?

Tags: widgets, admin, dashboard

On admin side under 'Screen Options' you can check which dashboard widgets you want on and off but how do you make it so that when a different user or myself logs back on the widgets remain on or off depending on what I set it to earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

> What does this plugin do?
>
> The plugin changes the administration backend and gives you the power
>   to assign rights on certain parts. Admins can activate/deactivate
>   every part of the menu and even parts of the sub-menu. Meta fields can
>   be administered separately for posts and pages. Certain parts of the
>   write menu can be deactivated separately for admins or non-admins. The
>   header of the backend is minimized and optimized to give you more
>   space and the structure of the menu gets changed to make it more
>   logical – this can all be done per user so each role and their
>   resulting users can have his own settings.